# Why do we multiply normalized fraction with 0.5 to get the significand in IEEE 754 representation?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

I have a question about the `pack754()` function defined in [Section 7.4 of Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#serialization).

This function converts a floating point number `f` into its IEEE 754 representation where `bits` is the total number of bits to represent the number and `expbits` is the number of bits used to represent only the exponent.

I am concerned with single-precision floating numbers only, so for this question, `bits` is specified as `32` and `expbits` is specified as `8`. This implies that `23` bits is used to store the significand (because one bit is sign bit).

My question is about this line of code.

```
    significand = fnorm * ((1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f);
```

What is the role of `+ 0.5f` in this code?

Here is a complete code that uses this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> // defines uintN_t types
#include <inttypes.h> // defines PRIx macros

uint64_t pack754(long double f, unsigned bits, unsigned expbits)
{
    long double fnorm;
    int shift;
    long long sign, exp, significand;
    unsigned significandbits = bits - expbits - 1; // -1 for sign bit

    if (f == 0.0) return 0; // get this special case out of the way

    // check sign and begin normalization
    if (f < 0) { sign = 1; fnorm = -f; }
    else { sign = 0; fnorm = f; }

    // get the normalized form of f and track the exponent
    shift = 0;
    while(fnorm >= 2.0) { fnorm /= 2.0; shift++; }
    while(fnorm < 1.0) { fnorm *= 2.0; shift--; }
    fnorm = fnorm - 1.0;

    // calculate the binary form (non-float) of the significand data
    significand = fnorm * ((1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f);

    // get the biased exponent
    exp = shift + ((1<<(expbits-1)) - 1); // shift + bias

    // return the final answer
    return (sign<<(bits-1)) | (exp<<(bits-expbits-1)) | significand;
}

int main(void)
{
    float f = 3.1415926;
    uint32_t fi;

    printf("float f: %.7f\n", f);

    fi = pack754(f, 32, 8);
    printf("float encoded: 0x%08" PRIx32 "\n", fi);

    return 0;
}
```

What purpose does `+ 0.5f` serve in this code?

Comment: Something tells me that you didn't copy that line correctly. In particular, I think you added an extra set of parentheses.

Comment: @user3386109 The referenced link has the same comment and code `significand = fnorm * ((1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f);` and same types.  Agree if would work better as `significand = fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is an incorrect attempt at rounding.

```
long double fnorm;
long long significand;
unsigned significandbits
...
significand = fnorm * ((1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f);  // bad code
```

The first clue of incorrectness is the `f` of `0.5f`, which indicates `float`, is a nonsensical introduction of specifying `float` in a routine with `long double f` and `fnorm`.  `float` math has no application in the function.

Yet adding `0.5f` does not mean that the code is limited to `float` math in `(1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f`.  See `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` which may allow higher precision intermediate results and have fooled the code author in testing.

A rounding attempt does make sense as the argument is `long double` and the target representations are narrower.  Adding `0.5` is a common approach - but it is not done right here.  IMO, the lack of the author commenting here concerning `0.5f` hinted that the intent was "obvious" - not subtle, albeit incorrect.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099056/why-do-we-multiply-normalized-fraction-with-0-5-to-get-the-significand-in-ieee-7/40099140#comment67470776_40099140), moving the `0.5` is closer to being correct for rounding, but may mis-lead some into thinking the addition is done with `float` math, (it is `long double` math adding a `long double`product  to `float` causes the `0.5f` to be promoted to `long double` first).

```
// closer to rounding but may mislead
significand = fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f;

// better
significand = fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5L; // or 0.5l or simply 0.5
```

To round, without calling the preferred `<math.h>` rounds routines like `rintl(), roundl(), nearbyintl(), llrintl()`, adding the explicit type 0.5 is still a weak attempt at rounding.  It is weak because it rounds incorrectly with many cases.  The +0.5 trick relies on that sum being *exact*.

Consider

```
long double product = fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits);
long long significand = product + 0.5;  // double rounding?
```

`product + 0.5` itself may go through a rounding before truncation/assignment to `long long` - in effect [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).

Best to use the right tool in the C shed of standard library functions.

```
significand = llrintl(fnorm * (1ULL<<significandbits));
```

A corner case remains with this rounding is where `significand` is now one too great and `significand , exp` needs adjustment.  As well identified by [@Nayuki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40099140/2410359), code has other short-comings too.  Also, it fails on `-0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

The `+ 0.5f` serves no purpose in the code, and may be harmful or misleading.

The expression `(1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f` results in a `float`. But even for the small case of `significandbits = 23` for single-precision floating-point, the expression evaluates to (float)(2<sup>23</sup> + 0.5), which rounds to exactly 2<sup>23</sup> (round half even).

Replacing `+ 0.5f` with `+ 0.0f` results in the same behavior. Heck, drop that term entirely, because `fnorm` will cause the right-hand side argument of `*` to be casted to `long double` anyway. This would be a better way to rewrite the line: `long long significand = fnorm * (long double)(1LL << significandbits);`

---

Side note: This implementation of `pack754()` handles zero correctly (and collapses negative zero to positive zero), but mishandles subnormal numbers (wrong bits), infinities (infinite loop), and NaN (wrong bits). It's best to not treat it as a reference model function.

Comment: Would `significand = fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f` instead be better because it would round off the significand to the nearest integer? If not, why not?

Comment: I've got a similar function here. https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/ieee754

Comment: What is round mode is not `round half even`?  I suspect that is what the 0.5f is for.

Comment: @chux Could you please elaborate in a comment or answer of your own why that 0.5f is there? I don't understand the supposed purpose of that 0.5f in the first place, so I am having difficulty in appreciating the comments and the answers.

Comment: @LoneLearner `significand = fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits) + 0.5f` would be significantly worse because `fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits)` could have 23, 52, or 64 bits of precision but the `+ 0.5f` would force it to only 23 bits.

Comment: Give the comments by the author (that it encodes the floats "mostly") its safe to say that it might have been bad logic that didn't change the result so was left in and not noticed. Maybe it convinced the author over which way it would round.

Comment: Disagree with [the + 0.5f would force it to only 23 bits.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099056/why-do-we-multiply-normalized-fraction-with-0-5-to-get-the-significand-in-ieee-7/40108163#comment67471560_40099140)  `0.5f` will be promoted the wider type of `fnorm * (1LL<<significandbits)` which is `long double`.